# UINavigationBar in View Embedded in Navigation Controller - Add Custom View

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have a UIView that is embedded in a Navigation Controller, so I get the UINavigationBar for free.

What I'm trying to do is add append a custom view to it. Is this possible/desirable? I just want to add a simple view with some text.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a custom subview to your navigation bar:

[image: screenshot]

### Swift Source Code Example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    self.navigationItem.title = "Demo App";

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Compose, target: self, action: "compose");


    var notificationView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width - 40.0, 50.0));
    notificationView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 145.0/255.0, green: 45.0/255.0, blue: 37.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0);
    notificationView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
    notificationView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
    notificationView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    notificationView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
    notificationView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);

    var messageLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, notificationView.frame.size.width, notificationView.frame.size.height));
    messageLabel.text = "Error: text fields cannot be empty";
    messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;

    notificationView.addSubview(messageLabel);

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(notificationView);

}
```

Comment: this seems to be working great! Only thing is lets say I only want to add this to a certain view controller. Right now I'm adding it to a "detail view" and then when I navigate back to the "Master View" its still present. How do I only add it for a certain view controller?

Comment: You can create a property that store the notification custom view in your viewController. On viewDidDisappearAnimated() of the ViewController, you can remove the custom view.